# How to Show Multiple values in flask JSON Response

Tags: python, json, flask

```
    from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
from flask import request
from textblob import TextBlob
from collections import OrderedDict
app = Flask(__name__)
import pickle
import re
import string
translate_table = dict((ord(char),None)for char in string.punctuation)
@app.route('/res',methods=['POST'])
def Language_detection():
   

    if request.method == 'POST':
        postedData = request.get_json()
        print(postedData)
        #Get the data
        text = postedData["text"]        
        print(text)
        test_string = text
        res = test_string.split()
        w=[]
        for i in res:
            blob = TextBlob(i)
            s=blob.translate(to='en')
            w.append(s)
            listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in w])
            return jsonify({'response':listToStr})
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1',port='5000',debug=False)
```

**Here I have a language detection model once the user enter mixed language it will detect what are languages so results look like English Hindi Marathi so I have created flask for this model when I test through rest-client it is returning only the first element from list that is English I am new to flask any help highly appreciated **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `return` inside the `for` a loop. that is why you are getting the first element. to get all data to save `listToStr` in a list and then return that list outside of for loop.